# Can a class have no constructor?

Tags: java

This is a piece of code as an example, after this rest are just methods (look at bottom for maze class). So when this is instantiated, using

```
Maze labyrinth = new Maze();
```

and

```
System.out.println (labyrinth);
```

This will print out the grid array.
Is this legit? I thought all classes needed constructors how does it print out the 2-d grid array?

**Maze Class:**

```
public class Maze
{
    private final int TRIED = 3;
    private final int PATH = 7;
    private int[][] grid = { {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1},
                             {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1},
                             {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0},
                             {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},
                             {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1},
                             {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                             {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                             {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} };

    public String toString ()
    {
        String result = "\n";
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
        {
            for (int column=0; column < grid[row].length; column++)
            result += grid[row][column] + "";
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: The compiler creates one for you.

Comment: You can make it even more confusing: http://ideone.com/JN7lGS

Comment: For JVM bytecode it is apparently legal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478139/is-it-valid-to-have-a-jvm-bytecode-class-without-any-constructor

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It is not required to *explicitly* define a constructor; however, all classes must have a constructor, and a default empty constructor will be generated if you don't provide any:

```
public Maze() {
}
```

See [Default Constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor).

Comment: How does System.out.println (labyrinth); print out the grid array then?

Comment: Is `toString()` overridden in the actual class with custom print logic (in one of those methods you didn't show us)?  I just copied your class into a new Java project, and when I print it out, I get `Maze@50c8d62f` as expected; because custom classes by default don't have a method to print out their contents in a meaningful way.

Comment: `System.out.println` just calls the `toString()` method of the newly created `Maze` object.

Comment: So any class that has a tostring method and if i try to print out via the reference variable it will automatically call the tostring method?

Comment: @LouisWasserman actually println(Object) uses [valueOf](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @fvu which itself calls `toString`

Comment: @Aaron: Essentially, yes, as long as it has the proper signature (method name and parameters).  It must be exactly called `toString()` with no parameters, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't write the constructor explicitly, compiler will generate a no-args constructor by default.

```
public Maze(){

}
```

the above will be included If you don't write the constructor explicitly, compiler will generate a no-args constructor by default.

```
public Maze(){

}
```

the above will be included by the compiler.

for Example check the Byte code for this class:

```
public class ABC {

}
```

**BYTE CODE:**

```
public class sorting/ABC {

  // compiled from: ABC.java

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V         //Default no-args constructor included by the compiler
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init>()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lsorting/ABC; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

Comment: @Aaron nothing is advance. its a good practice to check the byte code of your written code. i'd suggest download bytecode outline as a eclipse plugin. :)

Comment: I'm not discreting your knowledge, but I have no idea what those statements mean in the bytecode. Just not at that level yet, I'm still a beginner :). Thanks for your help though, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

To be more accurate, the compiler automatically provides a *no-args* constructor for a class that doesn't have a constructor, this constructor calls the *no-args* constructor of the *superclass*, if the superclass doesn't have a *no-args* constructor, it's an error, if it does, that's fine.

If your class has no explicit *superclass*, then it has an *implicit* *superclass* (`Object`), which **does** have a *no-args* constructor.

Answer (score 7):

The typical answer to this question is "if you don't declare a constructor, a default constructor is created". That is *usually* true, but not *always*. It is possible for a class to have no constructor.

(An important distinction to draw here is that the JVM [does not require all class files to have a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.1); however, any class defined in *Java* [does have a default constructor if a constructor is not explicitly declared](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9). This answer is presenting an oddity where an example of the former is created from Java code).

Consider the following code, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589638/why-does-javac-create-an-additional-class/47589823#47589823):

```
public class Outer
{
    private class Inner {}

    void someMethod()
    {
        Inner inObj = this.new Inner();
    }
}
```

If you compile this with OpenJDK, you will find 3 class files:

```
Outer.class
Outer$Inner.class
Outer$1.class
```

`Outer$1` is the most unusual of these: it has literally nothing in it, not even a constructor:

```
Compiled from "Outer.java"
class Outer$1 {
}
```

whereas the `Inner` and `Outer` classes have the generated constructors:

```
Compiled from "Outer.java"
class Outer {
  Outer();        <------------- Generated Constructor
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  void someMethod();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Outer$Inner
       3: dup
       4: aload_0
       5: aconst_null
       6: invokespecial #3                  // Method Outer$Inner."<init>":(LOuter;LOuter$1;)V
       9: astore_1
      10: return
}
Compiled from "Outer.java"
class Outer$Inner {
  final Outer this$0;

  Outer$Inner(Outer, Outer$1);        <------------- Generated Constructor
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokespecial #1                  // Method "<init>":(LOuter;)V
       5: return
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why the compiler generated `Outer$1` and if recent compilers still do it? I don't see a reason for the compiler to generate this class from the provided source code. It looks like some sort of marker for the constructor of `Outer$Inner`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a constructor, a default constructor will be generated by the compiler.

However, any member variable that is not initialized when it's declared will be null.

In other words, if you don't assign a value to *grid* (like you do in your example) it will be null.

Your example works fine because you happen to assign a value to *grid* immediately upon declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not actually require an explicit constructor in the class description. If you do not include a constructor, then the Java compiler will create a default constructor with an empty argument.

Comment: The same answer has already been given [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13773736/650012). No point in adding the same answer again.

Answer (score -1):

if you mean that you want no one to make an Instance of your class directly i think you can make a constructor set it's access modifier to private and you only can make an instance of this class by a public static method which have access to this private constructor