# Android: Why does the Color class have a public constructor?

Tags: android

Why does the android Color class have a public constructor when all its members are static? Is it just a mistake?

Comment: You'd probably have to track down the Google engineer who wrote the `Color` class all those years ago, and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/graphics/java/android/graphics/Color.java) for the Color.java file shows that no Google engineer explicitly wrote a public constructor for the Color class.

The [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#Color()) for the Color class does list a public constructor, but Java has an [implicit default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9), and that is the constructor listed in the documentation.

The real possible questions here are either/or,

- Why does the Google Android documentation list implicit default constructors in the constructor section of class documentation?
- Why does Java have an implicit default constructor when I could possibly make a class that only has static members?

For the first point I don't think that is any mistake or a bad design decision of Google to decide to list the implicit default constructor. They could define a constructor in the class to restrict access to any constructors, but that would just require extra code, and uselessly creating a default constructor for a class that only has static members does not cause any misuse of the class.

For the second point it might make sense to have a compiler optimization to prevent any implicit default constructors in classes that have only static members, but that's a question for another thread.

tl;dr Nope, not a mistake.

Comment: @dragon66 I would still argue that this is not an individual developers problem to be solved, but rather a language feature that you may or may not like. Other languages approach it differently. If you really don't like it, you can go make a pull request, Android is open source.

Comment: Nope, even with a private constructor you can still instantiate it with reflection. The only way for an individual developer to solve this problem is to both implement a private constructor, and throw an exception in the private constructor. This is not a problem for an individual developer to solve. As I discussed around the second point there could be a compiler optimization around this, but that is still not a problem for an individual developer to solve.

Comment: Reflection is not hacking

Answer (score 0):

Probably consistency and potential future use are reasons for the engineer to write a constructor even if it does nothing.  But, the engineer may not have written the constructor.  A default public constructor is created by the compiler if no constructor is given.

See the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773710/can-a-class-have-no-constructor).  It links to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor).

The documentation, which is probably auto-generated to some extent, might inform you of the default constructors' existence, even if the engineer did not create it.