# Does a Java program need a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap, hashset

I have created a HashSet and a HashMap and I am currently unsure as to whether I need to now declare a constructor.

Can Java run without a constructor ?

```
private HashSet <String> allJewelCards = new HashSet <String>();
private HashMap <String, Diamond> allDiamonds = new HashMap <String, Diamond>();
```

Comment: Constructor for what? I think you're misunderstanding basic concepts here.

Comment: In addition to @MarounMaroun, the entry point in every java based application is the `public static void main(String[] arguments)` method (not considering web apps).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a class have no constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773710/can-a-class-have-no-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't explicitly declare a constructor it's the same as doing

```
public class SomeExample {

    public SomeExample() {}

}
```

As for your two fields `allJewelCards` and `allDiamonds`, they're initialized so you don't have an inherent need to declare them in a constructor.

Comment: implicit -> explicit ?

Comment: coffee -> Rogue. Fixed

Comment: @Rogue  ↑ Good one ;)