# Why does javac create an additional class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, outer-classes

I have compiled the following code (Methods and variables are elided for brevity):

```
// Outer.java
public class Outer
{
    private class Inner
    {
    }
    void someMethod()
    {
        Inner inObj = this.new Inner();
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Outer outerObj = new Outer();
    }
}
```

When I listed the classes created, it displayed the following:

```
Outer$1.class
Outer$Inner.class
Outer.class
```

**Outer** and **Outer$Inner** appear logical. What is the purpose of **Outer$1** class? What is the order of creation of these in time scale?

Comment: "What is the order of creation of these in time scale?" Why do you think it is important to know that?

Comment: Why not? It is to understand the javac's mechanism of creating classes.

Comment: Order seems to be `1. Outer.class 2. Outer$Inner.class 3. Outer$1.class`, when sorted by `date modified` column in Windows.

Comment: When would the order in which class files are created ever matter? Whether and when instances of classes are created at execution time would be relevant, but when the class files are created seems somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: In this case it matters since the curious creation of Outer$1.class will be somewhat demystified.

Comment: [Oak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883541/3788176) to the dupe explains it, sort of.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a complete answer, because JRE doesn't seem to mind if this extra class is missing. It's only generated by compiler and everything still works even if it's deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Curious. I'm not sure what this is for. But if you decompile the classes, you can see *how* it is used:

```
public class Outer {
  public Outer();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  void someMethod();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Outer$Inner
       3: dup
       4: aload_0
       5: aconst_null
       6: invokespecial #3                  // Method Outer$Inner."<init>":(LOuter;LOuter$1;)V
       9: astore_1
      10: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #4                  // class Outer
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #5                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: return
}

class Outer$Inner {
  final Outer this$0;

  Outer$Inner(Outer, Outer$1);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokespecial #1                  // Method "<init>":(LOuter;)V
       5: return
}

class Outer$1 {
}
```

So, `Outer$1` seems to contain nothing - not even a default constructor. But a reference to a `Outer$1` has to be passed to `Outer$Inner` to construct it. Mysteriously, the value passed in `someMethod` is `null` (line 5 in `someMethod`).