# Differentiate provided default no args constructor from declared one

Tags: java, reflection

Simple question: How can I differentiate a default constructor. i.e:

```
class AClass { } // will have a default no args constructor -> public AClass() {}
```

from one specified like:

```
class AClass {
    private final int i;

    public AClass() { i = 0; }
}
```

Checking the options reflection libraries provide I am not able to find any that allows me to distinguish one from another...

I've tried mostly with the methods provided by [`Class#get*Constructor(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Maybe I got tunnel vision, and I am forgetting something or there is another approach to this I am missing... any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

This is the method I'm using, there is where I need to detect if such constructor is user defined or not:

```
    protected void adaptAfterLoading(final Class<?> loadedClass) {
        Arrays.asList(loadedClass.getDeclaredConstructors()).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$ " + loadedClass.getDeclaredConstructors());
        Arrays
                .stream(loadedClass.getDeclaredConstructors())
                .filter(
                        ((Predicate<Constructor<?>>) Constructor::isSynthetic)
                                .negate())
                .map(ConstructorRep::loadFrom)
                .forEach(this::addConstructor);
    }
```

So... in case you were wondering why isSynthetic does not work:

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html):

> > **13.1. The Form of a Binary** - 
> >     7. Any constructs introduced by a Java compiler that do not have a corresponding construct in the source code must be marked as synthetic, ***except for default constructors***, the class initialization method, and the values and valueOf methods of the Enum class.

Comment: Why do you really want to know that?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [Constructor class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html)

Comment: I really doubt there is a way to differentiate it. The default constructor is added at compile time, since reflection is done at runtime, it has no difference.

Comment: `Why do you really want to know that?:` Imagine the next requirement, for a given class write a method that will create the skeleton code for such class definition, constructors with their respective arguments, so with methods, must have the same declared fields and so on... but if there is no explicitly declared method/constructor/field it should not write it on the skeleton class code definition

Comment: That doesn't even make sense... There is always a constructor in the compiled class, even if you don't specify it explicitely.

Comment: @DorianGray exactly ... I know there is always one, I want to know if its possible in any way to differentiate the one given by the compilation process or the one defined in at the source code w/o having access to the source code, just to the compiled class

Comment: Ni, there isn't.

Comment: There isn't always a constructor in a class - there are some very odd synthetic classes which end up without one. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883266/3788176).

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no way to detect that, as there is no difference in the compiled bytecode.

A class with default constructor

```
class AClass { } // will have a default no args constructor
```

is implicitely compiled as

```
class AClass { 
    AClass() {}
}
```

The first form is merely syntactic sugar.

Also your next example

```
class AClass {
    private final int i;

    public AClass() { i = 0; }
}
```

Could be written with a default constructor in an equivalent form

```
class AClass {
    private final int i = 0;
}
```

Beside, I fail to see a use case where you would have to detect that.

Comment: read the comment on my question for **Why do you really want to know that?**